# Decoupling Capacitor Loop Length vs Loop Area

Tags: transistors, capacitor, pcb, inductance, decoupling-capacitor

When considering inductance reduction, what is considered more important? Reducing the loop length or the loop area? Below are two examples for visualisation, I am ignoring a lot of ways to reduce inductance (e.g. groundplanes, via teadrops):

[image: Loop Area Reduction]

[image: Loop Length]

Assuming both loop lengths are the same, why would loop area impact inductance?

Comment: you can make the traces wider, too. the interaction with the ground plane makes the situation 3 dimensional (acknowledging that the question states this should be ignored)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *When considering inductance reduction, what is considered more
> important? Reducing the loop length or the loop area?*

Loop area is the most important consideration.

When the wires are close (forming a smaller loop area) the magnetic field on one wires tends to cancel out the magnetic field from another. That reduces loop inductance.

If you use [this parallel wire calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/parallel-wire-inductance/) and mess around with values you'll get the gist.

Answer (score 5):

See [non-inductive windings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifilar_coil). A long wire, looped back on itself so it presents very little area, has a very low inductance. Area, not length, is the factor that controls the inductance. The magnetic field of one wire is substantially cancelled by the other.

[image]

Image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifilar_coil)

Answer (score 5):

Area is what is most important. Also what is inside the loop if there is something there with significant magnetic properties.